# I can't find what I did wrong in this piece of python code

Tags: python

When I try to run this piece of code:

```
capitals = ["Lisbon", "Madrid", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", 
"Reykjavik", "Dublin", "Stockolm", "Rome"]
client_name = "Me"
while True:
answer = input(client_name + ": ")
if answer == "What is the capital of Germany?"
print(capitals[3])
else:
print("I don't understand!")
```

It gives me this error:

```
File "chatbot.py", line 4
answer = input(client_name + ": ")
     ^
```

But I don't understand what I did wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: if missing colon and answer missing indentation

Comment: where should I put the colon?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation and missing ":" at the end of if:

```
capitals = ["Lisbon", "Madrid", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", 
"Reykjavik", "Dublin", "Stockolm", "Rome"]
client_name = "Me"
while True:
    answer = input(client_name + ": ")
    if answer == "What is the capital of Germany?":
        print(capitals[3])
    else:  
        print("I don't understand!")
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
capitals = ["Lisbon", "Madrid", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", 
            "Reykjavik", "Dublin", "Stockolm", "Rome"]
client_name = "Me"
while True:
    answer = input(client_name + ": ")
    if answer == "What is the capital of Germany?":
        print(capitals[3])
    else:
        print("I don't understand!")
```

the indentation in python is part of the code and you are missing ":" after the if statement

Comment: Yeah I just realized that! Duhh! Thank you for the help.